# Как правильно сделать update в spring data

Tags: spring-data

Есть некий файл (100K- строк) который по расписанию (раз в месяц) выкачивает и его содержимое должно быть записанно в БД. Как это сделать используя spring data?

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону [Spring batch](https://spring.io/projects/spring-batch#overview)

Comment: Я смотрел, но не нашел как **Spring batch** работает с .xlsx

Comment: Это только один из подходов, который позволит избежать много самописных вещей. 
Возвращаясь к вашей задаче, можно считывать файл и записывать напрямую по строчно или JDBC batch?. Но какие у вас ограничения по скорости? по памяти? нужно ли управлять транзакциями?

Comment: Ограничений по скорости нет, файл будет выкачиваться в наименьшую активность пользователей.

Comment: я бы делал следующим оброзом: считать файл (или по строчно считывать) далее JdbcTemplate, batch https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbc-jdbctemplate